# Where to download the NPAPI?

Tags: npapi, browser-plugin

I've been searching for about an hour now, I already feel kinda dumb. Where can I find a download for the NPAPI ? I've skimmed the [Gecko Plugin API Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_Plugin_API_Reference#page-files) a little bit, but couldn't find a downloadlink. I also downloaded the [Gecko SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_SDK), which eerily was called *xulrunner sdk* after downloading (??), but Windows-search told me there was no `npapi.h` in the package.

Where can I downlaod the NPAPI ?

**Edit*:

### DOH - I was wrong. The `npapi.h` is contained in the Gecko SDK. I'm sorry.

Comment: also worth looking at the http://firebreath.org project as a reference; open source plugin framework, plenty of NPAPI example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The canonical source for the NPAPI headers is the [NPAPI SDK project](http://code.google.com/p/npapi-sdk/). The Gecko SDK headers (as well as the headers in the WebKit source) are based on those.

Comment: Just btw, can you tell me why `NPNetscapeFuncs` is not defined in `npapi.h`? Do I need the project you linked in the answer? Ty

Comment: *got it, it's in `npfunctions.h`, sorry. ;)